# Content elements suddenly moved outside of the gridelements container

Tags: typo3, typoscript, fluid, tx-gridelements

I experienced a strange behavior with TYPO3 CMS: I use the content element "Grid-Element" on multiple pages.

The "Grid-Element" CE always has different child elements like images or text. 
Today all child elements suddenly moved outside of "Grid-Element" on every page of the website. I had to fix them one by one manually. Basically nothing was lost but the structure was broken.

I also checked the edit history but there is nothing relevant to see.

I would like to know how this happened and how to prevent this from happening again. Any ideas ?

Comment: Do you mean the extension "gridelements"?

Comment: This can't happen by its own, there must be some change in the system (install extension, remove extension, cronjob) which affect this kind of change. Do you have more information about that?

Comment: There is no element named "Grid element" in TYPO3. Either you mean the element "Insert records" (in german "Datensatz einfügen") or you have an extension for this kind of CEs.

Comment: @Thomas I havent deployed anything in a long time and as far as I know there are no cronjobs beside the standard Typo3 cron. So its probaby caused by someone who did something in the backend. We do indeed use the Mask extension which has a lot of different CE

Comment: Can you post the structure of the content element? TypoScript, Fluid Template?

Comment: @Mathias,  sorry you were right. We are using the extension "gridelements" and this CE is coming from this extension

Comment: @Thomas, I am not sure were I can find this but here is the Git repo of this extension: https://github.com/TYPO3-extensions/gridelements

Comment: The extension says nothing about the content elements. You must have a configuration for each content element. This is stored in database.

Answer (score 3):

In 99% of the cases this happens when the TYPO3 core is updated without having gridelements installed. Running the database comparison will change the SQL configuration for the field colPos from signed to unsigned thus changing -1 to 0.

Since -1 is the indicator for child elements of a grid container, this indicator gets lost.

You can fix this by running:

```
UPDATE tt_content SET colPos = -1 WHERE tx_gridelements_container > 0
```

The other 1% were not really able to reproduce the cause for the symptom, so currently we don't know exactly what went wrong for them.

Answer (score 3):

**Update**: 1 of 2 incidents could be traced to a problem not in gridelements (see below).

I had this effect too.

## Fix / workaround

1. Check your datatype of `tt_content.colpos` in database: is it unsigned?
2. Update gridelements to latest version. The problem may have been fixed.
3. Do a DB compare and let TYPO3 change `tt_content.colPos` back to signed (not unsigned)
4. Apply workaround as Jo Hasenau suggested: `UPDATE tt_content SET colPos = -1 WHERE tx_gridelements_container > 0`

## Explanation

So, what (probably) happened is that colPos got changed to unsigned, resulting in all -1 values being changed to 0. Because of this, the structure of the gridelements was no longer being interpreted correctly.

The core sets colPos to unsigned, gridelements overrides it and sets it to signed.

This change in DB schema should not really happen, if everything worked correctly.

## Test Cases

These are my test cases:

1. When upgrading from 8 to 9, I deactivated all third party extensions before the update. During the upgrade, the schema had been changed to unsigned.
2. (After installation of extension ["min"](https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/min/) on a 8.7.24 system, the colPos got changed to unsigned too. This should not have happened. "min" is harmless and does not change the DB structure at all.)

---

**Update**: Test case 2 could be traced back to a (development) extension with a messed up composer.json.  This is a pretty obscure scenario which is probably very rare, but it did wreak havoc with listed extentions in TYPO3 PackageManager, resulting in gridelements schema not getting loaded.

Just for completeness sake: You can reproduce it by using the extension key of another **activated** extension in the composer.json of a **deactivated** extension, e.g. in ext1/composer.json:

```
"replace": {
  "ext2": "self.version",
  "typo3-ter/Uniolexample": "self.version"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When using gridelements you have a configuration for each content element. This is stored in the database, mostly on the root page.

For each field in the container you set the `colPos` number.
Your broken structure could've happened because of:

- Any change in database which overwrote the `colPos` value
- A change in the element configuration to use another `colPos` value

Answer (score 0):

There has been a bug fix recently that might fix the symptoms here too. So it seems we found the cause for the 1% mentioned in my other answer.

Please check out latest master too see if it fixes your problem too:
https://forge.typo3.org/issues/85511